# Add column to query, return inside mapped class in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

It's pretty simple. This works as intented:

```
>>> db.session.query(SomeModel).all()[0]
SomeModel(41330029-f21e-4022-aed5-e45e61ada399
```

But if I try to add another column, I get a tuple back:

```
>>> db.session.query(SomeModel, some_expression.label('foo')).all()[0]
(SomeModel(41330029-f21e-4022-aed5-e45e61ada399), None)
```

How do I get a flat result? That is, a `SomeModel` with a `foo` attribute inside, instead of as a sibling?

Answer (score 3):

For simple expressions I would use [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#using-column-property) added to the `SomeModel`, in which case it would be always an attribute of its instances.
Or, you could take a look at [Hybrid Attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) to do the same job.

If you only need this on occasion, then just set it as a property after the query execution:

```
results = db.session.query(SomeModel, some_expression.label('foo')).all()
for mod, att in results:
    mod.foo = att # or: setattr(mod, "foo", att)
results = [mod for mod, _attr in results]
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with column_property is the expression has to be defined at class evaluation, but I need to build the expression at query time (it's for calculating a distance based on HTTP querystring argument). The solution for appending the attribute to the class might me by best bet.